# Sorting a list of objects holding a vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

Is the following code supposed to produce compilation error according to C++11 (if so why?) or is it a problem with VC11?

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
struct A
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
};
int main()
{
    std::list<A> l;
    l.sort([](const A& a1, const A& a2){ return true; });
}
```

Visual C++ 2012 produces the following compilation error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(606): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory(1447) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(605) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(751) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits(743) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector(655) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\test2\test2.cpp(213) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int>
1>          ]
```

Comment: For reference, I can compile this just fine in Clang and GCC. So it's either your compiler or your settings.

Comment: @chrisaycock Oh well, going to create yet another VC11 bug report at Microsoft Connect...

Comment: I'd rather abandon it altogether.

Comment: Microsoft has published 2 update patches to vs2012.  Did you install them both?

Comment: @rohitsan Of course, I am using Update 2.

Comment: @rohitsan: VS2012 update 2 [does _not_ contain C++11 features of November CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/04/04/visual-studio-2012-update-2-now-available.aspx#10407828) (and [Nov CTP doesn't have automatic generation of moves either](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with Visual C++ 2012 (acknowledged by Microsoft on Connect: [Compile error in C++ code sorting a list of objects holding a vector of unique_ptr](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786386/compile-error-in-c-code-sorting-a-list-of-objects-holding-a-vector-of-unique-ptr)) and it was already fixed in Visual C++ 2013.

Also, I'd like to point out that an issue had nothing to do with the fact, that Visual C++ does not implicitly generate move constructors. If you explicitly delete all copy and move constructors in struct A (yes, it will make impossible inserting objects of type A into the list, but that is beside the point) in my original example the code still is not supposed to copy or move any objects and as such produce compilation errors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
struct A
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete;
};
int main()
{
    std::list<A> l;
    l.sort([](const A& a1, const A& a2){ return true; });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's "a problem with VC", but only because you're misusing Visual Studio.

VC++ implements r-value references, but it does *not* implement compiler-generated move constructors/assignment operators. Which means that, if you want a type to be moveable, you must write one yourself.

`A` is not a moveable type, so the various `std::list` functions will attempt to copy them. And they'll fail when they try to copy a `vector` of `unique_ptr`. Hence the compiler error.

If you want move-aware objects in VC++, you must write move constructors/assignments for them yourself.

Comment: Why would sorting a list (not a vector) require copying of anything? Isn't sorting is supposed to be implemented by changing "previous" and "next" pointers of double-linked list nodes?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is really in VC11, as [it doesn't implement C++11 feature of *automatically* generating move operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) (as already nailed by Nicol Bolas).

The following code compiles with VC10 SP1; in this code sample, move constructor is *explicitly* written (instead for move `operator=`, the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) is used).

```
#include <algorithm>  // for std::swap (for copy-and-swap idiom)
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;

    A(A&& other)
        : v( std::move(other.v) )
    {
    }

    A& operator=(A other)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    friend void swap(A& lhs, A& rhs)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(lhs.v, rhs.v);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<A> l;
    l.sort( []( const A& , const A& ){ return true; } );
}
```

Comment: I quite aware of what move constructor is and the fact that VC11 does not implicitly generate them. That does not explain in the slightest WHY VC11 wants to copy or move an object of type A while performing a sorting of a *list*.

Comment: Well, then you may find the answer in STL source code. I understand your point.